# Can't delete SQLite database using Qt with QML transaction

Tags: sqlite, qt, qml, system.data.sqlite

Trying to use localstorage example in Qt 5.14, the database is locked and can't be deleted.

on Qt documentation it's saying:
"Database connections are automatically closed during Javascript garbage collection."

but that is not the case...

```
function dbInit()
{
var db = LocalStorage.openDatabaseSync("Activity_Tracker_DB", "", "Track exercise", 1000000)
try {

    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS trip_log (date text,trip_desc text,distance numeric)')
    })

    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error creating table in database: " + err)
    };
}

function dbGetHandle()
{
try {
    var db = LocalStorage.openDatabaseSync("Activity_Tracker_DB", "",
                                           "Track exercise", 1000000)
} catch (err) {
    console.log("Error opening database: " + err)
}
return db
}

function dbInsert(Pdate, Pdesc, Pdistance)
{
var db = dbGetHandle()
var rowid = 0;
db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO trip_log VALUES(?, ?, ?)',
                  [Pdate, Pdesc, Pdistance])
    var result = tx.executeSql('SELECT last_insert_rowid()')
    rowid = result.insertId
})
return rowid;
}

function dbReadAll()
{
var db = dbGetHandle()
    db.transaction(function (tx) {var results = tx.executeSql(
                'SELECT rowid,date,trip_desc,distance FROM trip_log order by rowid desc')
    for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
        listModel.append({
                             id: results.rows.item(i).rowid,
                             checked: " ",
                             date: results.rows.item(i).date,
                             trip_desc: results.rows.item(i).trip_desc,
                             distance: results.rows.item(i).distance
                         })
        }
    })
}
```

How can I unlock/close the database?

Comment: please clarify the question. Do you try to delete the file from FS while the application running? Did your code execution failed due to the file is locked? What exactly do you want to do? What your code should explain?  Btw, closing the connection doesn't necessarily mean that the file handler releases too.

Comment: I need to replace .sqlite file during application running

Comment: What a reason to replace this file?

Comment: because on my application many pepole have to be able to use it and I did make create individual database for each users and one main. the main is updated each time one user make change and the main database update all user database every change

Comment: Solved with replacing all database transaction to c++, with Qt + js, database connection is never closed